# Extract Closed Caption from TV signal

Tags: arduino, signal-processing, television

I dont know nothing about TV signals, but I'm thinking if have a way to connect a TV signal receiver into a PC or an Arduino and decode the vídeo, audio, and text (closed caption) form the signal.

I'm open to sugestions like which hardware I need to use to receive this signal and how to decode it to my PC.

Anyone have an ideia?

Comment: Do you at least know if the signal you can get is NTSC?   Basic NTSC signals are described fairly well in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTSC

Answer (score 2):

The Nootropic Video Experimenter shield allows you to easily decode closed captioning: http://nootropicdesign.com/ve/

Here's the writeup on the project with source code: http://nootropicdesign.com/projectlab/2011/03/20/decoding-closed-captioning/

Comment: Do you know if this still works for Digital Cable (Still delivered over cable wire)?